# Multithreaded program, condition variable destruction on catching signal

Tags: c++, multithreading, condition-variable

The following is my multi threaded program.

```
#include<csignal>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

void signalHandler(int signum)
{
  std::cout<<"SigNum"<<signum;

  exit(signum);
}

int main()
{
  signal(SIGABRT, signalHandler);
  signal(SIGINT, signalHandler);
  signal(SIGSEGV, signalHandler);
  Context context;
  context.launch();
}
```

The Context class is as follows

```
class Context
{
  private:
  boost::condition_variable _conditionVariable;

  public:
  void launchThread1()
  {
    std::cout<<"Launch Thread1";
    /** Continuously and Asynchronously read data from the socket **/
    /** Act on the data, conditionVariable is involved            **/
  }

  void launchThread2()
  {
    std::cout<<"Launch Thread2";
    /** Continuously and Asynchronously read data from the socket **/
    /** Act on the data, conditionVariable is involved            **/
  }

  void launch()
  {
    boost::thread thread1(boost::bind(&Context::launchThread1,this ) );
    boost::thread thread2(boost::bind(&Context::launchThread2,this ) );

    std::cout<<"Joining Thread1"<<std::endl;
    thread1.join();
    std::cout<<"Joining Thread2"<<std::endl;
    thread2.join();
  }
};
```

Since thread1 runs continuously, therefore control never reaches the point where  thread2 can be joined to the main thread.

Thus the prints are

```
Joining Thread1
```

Now, a signal SIGINT is thrown. When the exit(signum) is called in signalHandler, I get the following error

```
boost::condition_variable::~condition_variable(): Assertion `!pthread_mutex_destroy(&internal_mutex)' failed 
Segmentation Fault
```

Is this because thread2 has not been joined to the main thread?. If Yes, is there a way that I can explicitly stop thread2 in signalHandler? Will I have to make the thread a data member of Context? How safe is this approach? Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of exit(blah) which is generally frowned on, why don't you put an atomic flag in, and make the threads stop looping when it gets set?  Then in your signal handler you set the flag, the threads stop themselves, main joins both, and the program terminates normally with all destructors called etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

1 - you exit the main as soon as the threads are spawned. You should stay in a loop or wait for the threads to rejoin.

2 - In the event handler, just set a boolean flag to tell the thread to quit

3 - your threads should look at that variable and exit if it goes true

If the variable is just a boolean flag you don't need a mutex to protect it from concurrent access

Comment: We both gave the same answer at the same time, but I think your point 1 is wrong - he does wait on a join.  Also, just to be "good", I'd prefer a std::atomic<bool>, though you are probably right that it would work anyway.

Comment: I want to put the flag logic in the signalHandler class, not inside the threads. I'm not allowed to change the code inside the threads

Comment: You want to shoot them down in the middle of whatever they are doing?  That sounds a little drastic?  I hope they don't have any nasty handles open when it happens ...

Comment: plus1 for @AndyNewman. You should let the Thread see the variable and exit gracefully. I didn't notice the Join() actually

Comment: If you can't change the Thread at least you should identify the conditions on which the Thread will exit and trigger such condition on the event handler

Comment: The threads never end unless forced to by a signal/exception. If left to their own, they will keep listening on the socket for eternity and beyond. They never end themselves. Since the exit is always externally enforced, cant the check just be in signalHandler(external)

Comment: thread1 and thread2 are locally created in launch(). How do I access them in signalHandler??

Comment: So if there isn't any graceful way to stop the thread all I can see is a fundamental design flaw

Comment: The thread is supposed to continuously listen for data. Only situation it exits is when something bad happens. In that case, do I make it 1. stop listening to the socket 2. Complete the logical execution of the data it currently possess 3. exit the thread

Comment: Ok so you have at least one condition: just make the bad happen in your event handler and the thread will quit (you can rejoin it in the main thread).